# How do i save an attachment to documents in my C# e-mail application useing OpenPop

Tags: c#, email, attachment, openpop

I'm stuck!!! i need to know how to save an attached file to documents, could some one please provide me with a code snip it or something that works, iv been looking for days :(

I am using a third party dll called OpenPop. reading emails works with 2 forms one to display a list of emails and the other to view there content.

This works fine.

`Pop3Client pop3Client = (Pop3Client)Session["Pop3Client"]; // Creating new PopClient
                    int messageNumber = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["MessageNumber"]);
                    Message message = pop3Client.GetMessage(messageNumber);
                    MessagePart messagePart = message.MessagePart.MessageParts[1];
                    lblFrom.Text = message.Headers.From.Address; // Writeing message.
                    lblSubject.Text = message.Headers.Subject;
                    lblBody.Text = messagePart.BodyEncoding.GetString(messagePart.Body);`

This second portion of code displays the contents of the attachment, but that's only useful if its a text file. i need to be able to save the attachment. also the bottom section of code i have here over writes the body of my message, so if i recive an attachment i cant view my message body.

`if (messagePart.IsAttachment == true)
                    {
                        foreach (MessagePart attachment in message.FindAllAttachments())
                        {
                            if (attachment.FileName.Equals("blabla.pdf"))
                            {
                                // Save the raw bytes to a file
                                File.WriteAllBytes(attachment.FileName, attachment.Body);  //overwrites MessagePart.Body with attachment
                            }
                        }
                    }`

Comment: You might need to provide some, you know, information.

Comment: Please could you, try taking a second look, i have provided more info.

Comment: No one will answer my question, cuz u marked it down, but there is enuff info there!!!!

Comment: Perhaps you should look at how your 'extra info' is formatted and decide whether that's suitable for someone to wade through before throwing a fit.

Comment: I agree with @yamen. If you put so little effort in asking a question, do not expect us to act on it. But in general, questions about 'third party dlls' should go to the 'third party' websites. And we are voting down bad questions in order to make people ask questions correctly in the first place - that makes this site useful.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :)

Get the file path of the attachment which is the variable 'filePath'
emailChangeRequest is the name of the email

```
MailAttachment oAttch = new MailAttachment(filePath.ToString(), MailEncoding.Base64);
emailChangeRequest.Attachments.Add(oAttch);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for giving a solution based on a question with zero information.